# DeserializeObject array to object gives no result

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

When I try to deserialize the json I receive from an external source my program won't map the childobjects when I use `value.first()`.

```
private Class1 class1List;

public List<Class1> Class1List
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Class1> { class1List };
    }
    set
    {
        class1List = value.First();
    }
}
```

If I want it to work I have to alter the `class1List` to a `List` and have to remove `.First()`. The problem is that the `List`will always only contain one element and for internal storage and usage it would be best if I can get only the first element and store that as an object. The json I receive cannot be altered. (if Serialize my objects the json looks the same).

```
{
  "Class1List":[
    {"Class2List":[
      {"Name":"test"}
    ]}
]}
```

Edit: Removing the get makes it work
Edit 2 : altering the get to this also makes it work

```
get
{
    if (class1List != null)
    {
        return new List<Class1> { class1List };
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well I guess json.net is seeing [null] when it is expecting null and freak out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are that particular not add private member I have tried an another solution

```
  var selctedList = JObject.Parse("YOUR JSON").SelectToken("Class1List").ToString();

  var class1List = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(selctedList, new Class1Converter());



  public class Class1
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

  public class Class1Converter : JsonCreationConverter<Class1>
        {
            protected override Class1 Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
            {
                return new Class1();
            }

        }

        public abstract class JsonCreationConverter<T> : JsonConverter
        {

            protected abstract T Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject);

            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
                                            Type objectType,
                                             object existingValue,
                                             JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                try
                {

                    // Load JObject from stream
                    JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

                    var lp = jObject[jObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).FirstOrDefault()];

                    JObject kl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject[]>(lp.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

                    // Create target object based on JObject
                    T target = Create(objectType, kl);

                    // Populate the object properties
                    serializer.Populate(kl.CreateReader(), target);

                    return target;
                }
                catch (Exception er)
                {
                    throw er;
                }
            }

            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
                                           object value,
                                           JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I read it somewhere but I can't find the source now and my explanation might be wrong, but the solution work.**

Json.Net require you to return the object that Json.Net created during parsing.

```
class BaseClass
{

    internal Class1 class1List;
    private List<Class1> _class1List;
    public List<Class1> Class1List
    {
        get
        {
            return _class1List;
            // return new List<Class1> { class1List };
        }
        set
        {
            class1List = value.First();
            _class1List = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My goal was to prevent the use of a list internal for performance and storage purposes